# Varshamov-Gilbert, question about proof with probabilistic method

Tags: information-theory, binomial-distribution, probabilistic-method

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, and take $S_1, \dots, S_d \sim Bernoulli(0, 1)$.

Define for $v \in \{0,1\}^d$ the ball $B(v, d/2) = \{w \in \{0,1\}^d : \|v - w\|_1 \leq d/2\}$.

At p.144 of the [lecture notes](https://stanford.edu/class/stats311/Lectures/full_notes.pdf) of John Duchi, in the proof of the Varshamov-Gilbert bound, the following is stated:

$$2^{-d} B(v, d/2) = \mathbf{P}(S_1 + S_2 + \dots + S_d \leq d/4)$$

A quick computation gives me (from the CDF of a Binomial distribution)

$$\mathbf{P}(S_1 + S_2 + \dots + S_d \leq d/4) = \sum_{i=0}^{d/4} {d \choose i} (1/2)^i (1 - 1/2)^{d-i} = 2^{-d} \sum_{i=0}^{d/4} {d \choose i}$$

Which looks more to me like $B(v, d/4)$ instead of $B(v, d/2)$. What am I missing ?

Comment: Looking at pg 144, Duchi is working in $\{-1,1\}^d$, not $\{0,1\}^d$ (but the $S_i$s are still $\{0,1\}$). This accounts for the $d/2$ instead of $d/4$.

Comment: You are right, he is working in $\{-1, 1\}^d$, and I missed that. Indeed in that case, the $L_1$ norm is twice the Hamming metric. So the notation becomes slightly weird, as we are also working with $B(\mathbf{0}, d/2)$ which is not an element of this hypercube ($B(\mathbf{1}, d/2)$ would be better). Anyhow that's just detail, thanks stochasticboy321